# What is the default iOS system font for Hebrew?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, fonts, hebrew

[image]

I'm trying to figure out what's the system font that is used for Hebrew on the iOS Home screen. ( See the attached sample image ).
I'm aware that Apple is using SF Pro as the default system font since iOS 11, but the SF Pro font doesn't seem to support Hebrew, so I'm wondering what the fallback font for Hebrew is.

Thanks!

Comment: **FWIW**, in some applications I seem to get the Hebrew set from Lucida Grande as a substitute/replacement font when the glyphs aren't present in the selected font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Gereon's answer is technically true,
.SFUI-Regular is part of Apple's SF / SF pro fonts, which don't seem to support Hebrew. So it seems to fall back to Arial bold. I added the text in Arial Bold 12 to the image for reference

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On the device, this font is called `.SFUI-Regular`, and this is the font you get when using `UIFont.systemFont(...)`

Paste this in a playground to reproduce:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 300, height: 40))
label.text = "זה מבחן"

print(label.font)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = label
```