# List of default fonts used on iOS for non-Latin scripts?

Tags: ios, unicode, fonts

When making an iOS app, you can set the font of a user interface element to the `system` font. By "system" font here, I mean the font that user interface elements are rendered in, not fonts that come pre-installed with the operating system.

The `system` font on iOS for Latin scripts is San Francisco. However, San Francisco doesn't have the full Unicode character set, and when rendering non-Latin scripts in user interfaces using the `system` font, iOS uses different fonts depending on the script.

I'm looking for a reference to what these different fonts are but I haven't been able to find a good source. Here's what I've pieced together so far from different sources (and some of these may be wrong):

- Arabic script uses [Geeza Pro](https://web.archive.org/web/20210414015419/http://www.org.uib.no:80/smi/ksv/ArabicFonts.html)
- Hebrew seems to use [Arial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63773639/555807)? I find this hard to believe since it's a Microsoft font.
- Japanese script uses Hiragino Sans
- Korean script uses AppleMyungjo
- Thai script possibly uses Thonburi?
- Simplified Chinese uses PingFang SC
- Traditional Chinese uses PingFang TC
- Hong Kong Chinese script uses PingFang HK

If anyone knows of a definitive source for this, please let me know.

Comment: Are you doing this for research purpose or what ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure since iOs 11 the default font used for Arabic is also SanFrancisco Pro. I remember a colleague complaining about it a few years ago. Maybe it's now default for all languages?

Comment: Wouldn't be that hard to write an app that displays non-latin sample text in the system font and then again the same text in all pre-installed fonts then screenshot the result and compare.

Answer (score 0):

source : [https://support.apple.com](https://support.apple.com/guide/pages-ipad/format-chinese-japanese-or-korean-text-tanfbd4156e/ipados)

For best results, use these recommended fonts:

Simplified Chinese: PingFang SC

Traditional Chinese for Taiwan: PingFang TC

Traditional Chinese for Hong Kong and Macau: PingFang HK

Korean: Apple SD Gothic Neo

Japanese: Hiragino Sans (sans serif) or Hiragino Mincho (serif)

Answer (score -1):

**Since iOS 11**

On iOS, iPad OS, macOS and tvOS.All supported languages except Arabic use `SF Pro`

For Arabic `SF Arabic beta`

On watchOS `SF Compact`
Source: Apple official website https://developer.apple.com/fonts/

[image: screenshot]